# monit check http response header

Tags: monit

unfortunately, the documentation is not clear about the HTTP content.

https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#HTTP

i want to monitor a specific response header, not the content itself, like this:

```
CHECK HOST example.de WITH ADDRESS example.de
 IF FAILED
   port 443 protocol https
   with ssl options {verify: enable}
   certificate valid > 15 days
   content == "Location: https://example.com/de/"
 THEN alert
```

As you see, I want to make sure the certificate is valid and the webserver is redirecting to the correct target url (so, only checking for 301 is not the solution).

**Content** in context of monit **seems not to include the response headers**.
I tried it with send/expect, but monit refuses to start then (I did not investigate that further, because I can't believe it's not possible to do it "right".

Monit status is `FAILED to [example.de]:443 type TCP/IP using TLS protocol HTTP` with `CONNECTION FAILED`, which is a lie. Because if I delete the "content" line, the check is green/ok.

Answer (score 0):

Latest Monit version (`5.25.3`) does not support check headers from response.